# Mercurial unreliable sub-repos. Any alternative?

Tags: mercurial, repository

I trying to like mercurial, but is driving me nuts.

I convert from SVN to it thinking in the promise of better workflows. Also, I use git in contract work, so I get the whole distributed idea. I choose mercurial for the promise of more simplicity and better windows support.

I'm a solo developer right now, working in a project that compromise 5 separate repos. Some commits are global and other locally applied to each one.

Normally, I commit each single repo, then fecth/push from the root.

But I found that:

- The 2 head thing. Exist a way to disable that forever?
- None of the GUI out there truly work for my workflow (I use MacHG, TortoiseHG, and try other half-attempts guis). I need to fall-back to command line for a workable push/pull behavior. No GUI understand subrepo, no understand that 2-head problem, so I need to fix/merge in command line.
- But the worst of all, is that subrepo are tooo unreliable. Almost each 2-3 days I get "abort: unknown revision ****". Sometimes the hex value have a "+" at the end. Others not.

Sometimes is the ONLY change in the repo.

I don't wanna fix this behavior, I wanna a working replacement to subrepo, that let me:

- Commit each sub repo
- At the end, push+pull, automerge anything that make sense... and if work with the available GUIS better.

Comment: Are you by any chance storing your clones in any type of synchronization tool, like Dropbox or similar? Also, have you tried disabling antivirus for your clone folders?

Comment: No, I have a regular folder. I don't have AV (also this happend in OSX too)

Comment: Can you explain the function\role of having 5 separate repositories for a single project?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "the two head thing" but having two heads is a very normal part of a DVCS workflow.  If having two heads feels like a problem for you, then you probably need to review the basics again.  I certainly don't what what disabling two-heads would mean.

Comment: @David Lynch: Comming from SVN is normal put everything in a single repo because SVN let you checkout a sub-path. My project is for a iPhone app, that also have a Server, scripts, plugins, website.

@Ry4an: Then why in git I never have that problem? Using 2 heads is redundant with the concept of branch/bookmarks. Also, no one of the GUI tools know about that

Comment: i'm confused? - tortoisehg can defiently cope with multiple heads, it's a normal way to do short lived branches. maybe try http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/GitConcepts

Answer (score -3):

You are a bit confused in my humble opinion.
Mercurial and GIT are distributed versoin control, so the repository is always...the same.

You have your own copy of the repository with all the history. There is no "sub"-repo.

All repositories are "peer", and you can use clone them to do "sub" developement.
Every developer must have at least one peer repository.

Take a look at this good tutorial http://hginit.com/

Hope this helps

Comment: subrepos are a relatively new feature of mercurial somewhat equivalent to svn::externals i think the OP is correctly refering to them http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/subrepos

Comment: No, in fact mercurial has introduced suprepos. I haven't worked with them yet, but have a look at their [site][1].

  [1]: http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/subrepos

Comment: Thank you for your comments!
Anyway I read "As this is a complex new feature, there are a number of rough edges. Most commands such as diff and status are currently completely unaware of subrepositories. Currently only update, commit, and push are subrepo-aware. "
So this feature shoud be evaluated with care

Comment: So, that is my question. SubRepo is not reliable yet, what else I can do?